# How to guard multiple declaration in x86 assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I have written x86 assembly code for printing a string and printing the value of a register in hexadecimal format. I have created two separate asm files, `print_string.asm` for printing a string and `print_hex.asm` for printing a hexadecimal value. I have included those files in my `main.asm` file. Now the problem is `print_hex.asm` also includes `print_string.asm` for printing a string. So the assembler is showing `symbol redefined` error! How can I solve this problem? I am using *NASM* as the assembler.

Here is my assembly code:

**main.asm**

```assembly
mov ax, 0x7c0
mov ds, ax
mov bx, STRING
call PRINT_STRING

mov dx, 0x4f3e
call PRINT_HEX

jmp $

%include "printstring.asm"
%include "printhex.asm"

STRING:
    db 'Hello World', 0

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

**print_string.asm**

```assembly
PRINT_STRING:
    pusha
    mov ah, 0x0e

    PLOOP:
        cmp byte [bx], 0
        je POUT
        mov al, [bx]
        int 0x10
        add bx, 1
        jmp PLOOP

    POUT:
        popa
        ret
```

**printhex.asm**

```assembly
; This routine will print value of dx register
; into hex

; Hex Template Manipulation
mov bx, HEX_TEMP
add bx, 5

HLOOP:
    cmp byte [bx], 'x'
    je HOUT
    mov ax, 0x000f
    and ax, dx
    cmp ax, 0x09
    jg HCHAR
    add ax, 0x30

HCOMM:
    mov byte [bx], al
    shr dx, 4
    sub bx, 1
    jmp HLOOP

HCHAR:
    sub ax, 0x0a
    add ax, 0x61
    jmp HCOMM

HOUT:

mov bx, HEX_TEMP
call PRINT_STRING

%include "printstring.asm"

HEX_TEMP:
    db '0x0000', 0
```

When I try to compile its showing following errors:

```
printstring.asm:1: error: symbol `PRINT_STRING' redefined
printstring.asm:5: error: symbol `PLOOP' redefined
printstring.asm:13: error: symbol `POUT' redefined
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're using NASM? If so you can take exactly the same approach you would use in a C header file and wrap your included asm file in an `%ifndef` - `%endif` block.

```
%ifndef PRINT_STRING_ASM
    %define PRINT_STRING_ASM
    ; body of print_string.asm 
%endif
```

If the file is included more than once then the `PRINT_STRING_ASM` macro will have been defined the second time through and the contents of the file will be skipped over.

Answer (score 4):

For your given `main.asm`, just remove the `%include "printstring.asm"` from `printhex.asm` It is included by `main.asm` already.

For a more general solution, remove all the `%include` statements, make each function a global/extern and assemble them separately. Then, link them together.

While a `%ifndef/%define/%endif` lock [similar to what is used in C for `.h` files] can be used, it is not advised because you've got code in the `.asm` files and might generate multiple copies of functions as private functions

Comment: In case I have an asm file containing only `%define`s which is generated from a C header file, is it also desirable to avoid `%ifndef`-`%define`-`%endif` guards?